# PostgreSQL drop all the even rows and output all the odd rows

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table, and I want to ignore all the even rows and output all the odd rows in PostgreSQL. The table is like:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 |

The code to create the sample table is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  col1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  col2 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('Cell 1', 'Cell 2');
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('Cell 3', 'Cell 4');
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('Cell 5', 'Cell 6');
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('Cell 7', 'Cell 8');
```

And that is what I expect:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

I know `row_number() over ()` can get the row number, but based on my understanding, it only works in `select` part, and I'm not sure if it works for `where` part.

It would be better if it can be solved by only ONE query.

Apppreciate any ideas! Thank you!

Comment: What is the column which provides the _ordering_ which you think exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here.  Assuming there be a third `id` column which maintains the sequence order, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM tmp
)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM cte
WHERE rn % 2 = 1;
```